# Disable Automatic URL detection for Elements with 'contentEditable' flag in IE

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, contenteditable

When i paste any text in any element with 'contentEditable' flag enabled, IE automatically finds the hyperlinks or email address and replaces them with

```
<a href="hyperlink">hyperlink</a>.
```

How can i disable this automatic url detection for elements(e.g. div, span etc.) with 'contentEditable' flag in IE or aleast get the actual text that was pasted in the div.

Best Regards,
Keshav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can. You'll need catch the `paste` event and set a brief timer that calls a function that removes links.

**Edit 30 September 2012**

IE 9 and above has the ability to switch this off. See Maxon's answer.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, there is no cross-version solution.
In IE9 there is opportunity, allowing to disable automatic hyperlinking:

```
document.execCommand("AutoUrlDetect", false, false);
```

More information: [http://msdn.microsoft.com](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa769893%28v=vs.85%29.aspx),
[http://bytes.com](http://bytes.com/topic/javascript/answers/152771-disable-automatic-detection-hyperlinks-contenteditable-ie-5-5-a)

Answer (score 0):

I use preventDefault on space key, enter key, tab key's keydown event to prevent URL detection. Tested on IE11 and Chrome.

```
document.getElementById("input").addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
  var SPACEKEY = 32;
  var ENTERKEY = 13;
  var TABKEY = 9;

  var whiteSpace = "";

  if (e.keyCode == SPACEKEY || e.keyCode == ENTERKEY || e.keyCode == TABKEY) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (e.keyCode == SPACEKEY) {
      whiteSpace = " ";
    } else if (e.keyCode == ENTERKEY) {
      whiteSpace = "\n";
    } else if (e.keyCode == TABKEY) {
      whiteSpace = "\t";
    }

    var selection = document.getSelection();
    var start = selection.anchorOffset > selection.focusOffset ? selection.focusOffset : selection.anchorOffset;
    var end = selection.anchorOffset > selection.focusOffset ? selection.anchorOffset : selection.focusOffset;

    $(this).text($(this).text().substring(0, start)
      + " "
      + $(this).text().substring(end));
    var range = document.createRange();
    range.setStart($(this)[0].firstChild, start + 1);
    range.setEnd($(this)[0].firstChild, start + 1);
    selection.removeAllRanges();
    selection.addRange(range);
  }
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it works for Chrome: Hold Ctrl+Alt to disable the links temporarily. This extension disables links when you hold Ctrl+Alt. This allows to select text from the middle of the link, and generally eases selection, eliminating the risk to click the link while copying it.